# Spam porn notifications from Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, spam

Regularly I've been getting Google Drive SPAM notifications saying that a file was shared with me and a porn / sexual message linked with it.

I'm familiar there's a block feature

- https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10613533

but thing is the files are coming from new emails.

What can be done to stop this?

Comment: create new google account and drop the old one

Comment: Known exploit with Google Drive. AFAIK, unfortunately, there's nothing that we the users can do to prevent them.